# Android thread Loop not work

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, listview

I use Looper.prepare and Looper.loop in Runnable's run function. But the problem is that the thread not loop at all, the Runnable just run one time. In Activity1, I use three Runnable threads, all looping. Two threads get Data and pictures from net constantly through "while" loop(needn't update UI), one thread select data and pic from local sqlite constantly through "Looper". The data is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......
new Thread(getMessageTask).start();
        getMessageHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                i++;
                System.out.println("niuanmata" + i);    //one appear the first one
                try {

                    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listMessages = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>)msg.obj;
                    boolean listchange = true;

                    if (oldMessages.size() != 0) {
                        if (listMessages.size() == oldMessages.size()) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < listMessages.size(); i++) {
                                Map<String, String> oldmessage = (Map<String, String>) oldMessages.get(i);
                                Map<String, String> newmessage = (Map<String, String>) listMessages.get(i);
                                if ((oldmessage.get("mID") != newmessage.get("mID")) || (oldmessage.get("mainContent") != newmessage.get("mainContent")) || (oldmessage.get("deadLine") != newmessage.get("deadLine"))) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (i == (listMessages.size() - 1)) {
                                    listchange = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (listchange) {
                        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, listMessages, R.layout.layout_invites,
                                new String[]{"mID", "creater", "mainContent", "deadLine", "mtype", "createrLogo"},
                                new int[]{R.id.tv_list_type, R.id.tv_list_name, R.id.tv_list_inviteword, R.id.tv_list_invitedate, R.id.tv_list_inviteid, R.id.iv_list_logo});
                        lvMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
                        oldMessages = listMessages;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

......
lvMessage.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {    //when creater click, update the message; when others click, reset the alarm

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}

.........
Runnable synchroDataTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            //data syschno
            while (IOHelper.loopjudge()) {
                 {
                     AccountsDB adb = new AccountsDB(MainActivity.this);
                     String thelastupdate = adb.getLastUpdate(account.getChatNO());     

                     Calendar calendar = IOHelper.StringToCalendar(thelastupdate);
                     calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30);   
                     String accountData = synchroDataWebservice(account.getChatNO(), IOHelper.CalendarToString(calendar));   //get the datas of the account synchroly

                     AccountBLL.saveDBofWebString(accountData, MainActivity.this, account);    //use static method to save the DB string as SQLite data
                }
            }
.........

@Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while (IOHelper.loopjudge()) {
......
}


.......
Runnable getMessageTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            //while (IOHelper.loopjudge() && (!stopThread)) {
                MessageDB messagedb = new MessageDB(MainActivity.this);
                List<MessageMain> messages = messagedb.getMessageByChatNO(account.getChatNO());
                ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listMessages = setMessaageListToMap(messages);
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.obj = listMessages;
                getMessageHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
            //}
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
......
```

In my limited experience with android, I use while to do the Loop in getMessageTask , because the data and UI's listview need to be updated constantly. But the listview can not be clicked. Then change to Looper, but the the UI's listview can't be updated constantly....

Comment: need the listview on UI to be updated constantly, according to the data from db. But not work. What's more, the UI turn to another activity suddenly once in a while, after I change the Runnable's loop from while to Looper. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I misunderstand the meaning of Looper, think the Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() as the while() loop, then make the mistake.
Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() just means that this thread can be looped, but I must write while loop or for loop by myself.